# vue-router: Active class issue when the route path is like "employees/add"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a project in Vue and using vue-router for routing. When the route is `/employees` the ***Employees*** menu item gets activated. But when the route is `/employees/add` both the ***Employees*** and the ***Add Employee*** menu items get activated. Have a look at the snap.

[image]

**Script**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: true,

      navLinks: [
        {
          icon: "people_alt",
          text: "Employees",
          route: "/employees",
          active: false,
          subLinks: [
            { text: "Add Employee", route: "/employees/add" },
            { text: "Employees", route: "/employees" }
          ]
        },

        {
          icon: "supervised_user_circle",
          text: "Drivers",
          route: "/drivers",
          active: false,
          subLinks: [
            { text: "Add Driver", route: "/drivers/add" },
            { text: "Drivers", route: "/drivers" }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<v-list dark dense>
        <v-list-group
            v-for="item in listWithSubMenus"
            :key="item.text"
            v-model="item.active"
            :prepend-icon="item.icon"
            active-class="link-active"
            :to="item.route"
            no-action
        >
            <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
            </template>
    
            <v-list-item
            v-for="subItem in item.subLinks"
            :key="subItem.text"
            :to="subItem.route"
            active-class="link-active"
            >
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default active class matching behavior is an `inclusive` match

use `exact` property in `vue-router`

you can read [more](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact)

```js
    <v-list-item
            v-for="subItem in item.subLinks"
            :key="subItem.text"
            :to="subItem.route"
            active-class="link-active"
            exact
            >
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
     </v-list-item>
```